# use empty object as initialState in createSlice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying write reducer for ticket object in my app and  I use createSlice for it like this:

```
    export const ticketSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ticket',
    initialState: { value: null },
    reducers: {
        ticketSet: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload;
        },
        ticketSetCategory: (state, action) => {
            state.value.category = action.payload;
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works fine but it's not so convenient to use state.ticket.value in useSelector.  I prefer state.ticket instead it. So I changed my reducer like it:

```
    export const ticketSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ticket',
    initialState: {},
    reducers: {
        ticketSet: (state, action) => {
            state = action.payload;
        },
        ticketSetCategory: (state, action) => {
            state.category = action.payload;
        }
    }
});
```

After that, the storage stopped working. The ticket value is always an empty object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`state = anything` is never a valid statement in an Immer-powered reducer, because it is neither *mutating* the state, nor *returning* a new value.

The short answer is that you want `return action.payload` here to replace the existing state.

For more details, see the extended writeup on this topic in our docs:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state